# Taking a user input string to form an array

Tags: java, arrays, user-input, drjava

I am trying to create an array that uses a user input string to form the base for the array. It's supposed to be an encryption program that takes the string the user enters and puts it in an array at the index 0, all the way down the column. For example, if I typed in car, the array would look like array[0][0] c, [1][0] a, [2][0] r. After the encryption, whatever car turns into would go into the second row, but for the life of me I can't even figure out how to create the first array.

So far my file looks like this:

```js
public class Csci1301_hw3 
{   //Start of class
  
  public static void main(String[] args)
  
  {  //Start of Main Method
    String userinput;
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence you would like to encrypt.");
    userinput = scan.nextLine();
    
    char current;
    int arraylength = userinput.length();
    
    char[][] outputarray = new char [arraylength][];
    
    for (int index=0; index < arraylength; index++);
    {
      if (current.charAt(0) < userinput.charAt(0))
      current = userinput.charAt(0);
      outputarray[0][0] = current;
      current++;
    }
```

```
String userinput;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a sentence you would like to encrypt.");
userinput = scan.nextLine();

char current;
int arraylength = userinput.length();

char[][] outputarray = new char [arraylength][];

for (int index=0; index < arraylength; index++);
{
  if (current.charAt(0) < userinput.charAt(0))
  current = userinput.charAt(0);
  outputarray[0][0] = current;
  current++;
}
```

This is my first coding class so I am very new to this, but even after rewatching lectures, reading my textbook, or even going over my professor's examples, I am unable to figure this out. The closest I got was it would just print out null for the entire array no matter what I typed.

Comment: it is not clear to me what the output would look like

Comment: ``char[][] outputArray = new char[userInput.length][2];`` At least I assume that you just want the second dimension of the array to be 2. And yes, I renamed the variables to be in line with java's naming conventions.

Comment: At this point in the code, there probably isn't an output just because of how jumbled my code is because I'm so lost on what I'm trying to accomplish. Basically, what I tried to initially explain is the full assignment I am working on, yet my code is at the very beginning of the work just because I'm stuck on creating the first array with the user input. What I'm trying to have the array do, is take user input, be it a single character or an entire sentence, and adjust to the size of the input and keep it all in the first index column, so [0][0], [1][0], [2][0] etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of things you might want to check, first your *current* variable,you should assign a value to it before using it in an if statement. second, I think you might want to consider using the index variable inside the if statement like:

```
userinput.charAt(index);
```

and in other places too. Because you want to go over all the chars in a string. the last thing I wasn't sure about is why incrementing the *current* variable?

update:

```
    String userInput;
    
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence you would like to encrypt.");
    userInput = stdin.nextLine();
    
    int arraylength = userInput.length();
    
    char[][] outPutArray = new char [arraylength][2];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++)
    {
        outPutArray[i][1] = userInput.charAt(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i< outPutArray.length; i++)
        System.out.print(outPutArray[i][1]);
```

Comment: I've only been coding for about 3 months now so I assume most of what I'm doing/trying is wrong in some form or another. About incrementing the current value, we just learned if statements about 3 weeks ago so I'm still very shakey about doing them correctly so I apologize if my code seems like a jumbled mess because at this point that's not a far off guess.

Comment: you don't need to apologize, you are doing well. I am a student and I'm still learning too. Answering these question are benefiting me as much as they benefit you.

Comment: Sorry for the super late reply, just got home from work. Anyway, following your code's example, I'm still getting an error. Typing in your code character for character is giving me a "cannot find symbol: symbol variable i" error.

Comment: No worries.  For the solution, make sure that you don't put a semicolon at the end of the for loop/ if statement. I think I had the same error when I was trying to run your original code. It's a mistake that I also make sometimes. Also remember here I'm assuming that there are only two columns. I hope this one helps.

Comment: Ok, no yeah. I did literally exactly what you just said and put the semicolon at the end of the header on my for loop so it never read the body of the loop. That's why I kept getting errors.